# Animate (fade) s:Image in pure Actionscript Flex SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5, fade

I need a simple fade effect on an embedded image but I can't seem to figure it out. "fade" and "tween" simply did not work at all. It seems that animate is the effect to use in the latest Flex SDK.

What I have now:

```
[Embed(source="assets/Back.png")]
private static const fullScreen:Class;
private var fullScreenButton:Image;
fullScreenButton = new Image();

fullScreenButton.source = fullScreen;
fullScreenButton.verticalAlign = "top";
fullScreenButton.horizontalAlign = "left";
fullScreenButton.visible = false;
private var animate:Animate
animate = new Animate();

// function is activated when video is loaded.

animate.duration = 2000;
animate.startDelay = 1000;
fullScreenButton.visible = true;
animate.target = fullScreenButton;
animate.play();
```

With this code there is no effect. What am I doing wrong? (this could well be the wrong way of doing it so don't assume animate is the method that I want to use specifically).

Comment: Maybe this it not what you want to hear... but try TweenLite. The easiest, fastest, and more powerful Tweening engine for AS3, or JS. I have been using for years in all my projects. Those 5 lines of code would something this: TweenLite.to(fullScreenButton,2,{autoAlpha:1,delay:1});

Comment: It seems like overkill, I only need to fade a single element.

Comment: Maybe... but with TweenLite you would have already solved this. I'll post an answer with the complete code so you can copy paste if you wish.

Comment: Make sure fullScreenButton added or not in stage or container ?

Comment: I've never heard of "fullScreenButton". If you mean full screen setting in a flex app settings file then it's disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I figured it out. There are virtually no examples of fading components in Flex but with pure actionscript so hopefully this might be helpful to someone.

```
private var fade:Fade = new Fade();
fade.target = fullScreenButton;
fade.duration = 1000;
fade.alphaFrom = 1;
fade.alphaTo = 0;

// Call this when want to start the effect.

fade.stop(); // this is recommended to stop previous effects.
fade.play();
```

This will fade out the component (image in this case) in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

With TweenLite you would do it this way.

1) download the library files from Greensock's website http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

2) Copy those files in your project folder or in your repository of AS files.

3) Import statements

```
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.plugins.AutoAlphaPlugin;
```

4) Activate the AutoAlpha plugin. What autoalpha does is that instead of just tweenning the alpha value, it also activates/deactivates the visible property when alpha is 0 or when tweenning from alpha 0. You could just tween alpha, but in your code you are indeed using visible = false

```
TweenPlugin.activate([AutoAlphaPlugin]);
```

5) Do the dance

```
TweenLite.to(fullScreenButton,2,{autoAlpha:1,delay:1});
```

Comment: In the end I figured it out. Your method is simple but using an entire library for one effect is inefficiency. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I understand your point, and yeah maybe it's an overkill for 1 fade... As a side note, if you are considering making more tweens in the future you should really take a look at tweenlite. It's faster and more efficient than Adobe's engine, and it only adds a few kb to the compiled file (swf, ipa, etc). Any modern UI uses tweens intensively and tweenlite is by far the best choice for AS3 or even JS.